# How to set the load to "on" by removing voltage from the resistor base?

Tags: transistors

I know how to power the load with the transistor when the base is "on".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Kv0e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I sometimes need the opposite, to power the load when the base is "off". How to do that with transistors?

Comment: You will fry your BJT without a base resistor. Think of the base-emitter junction as a diode.

Comment: what do you mean by `base is off`?

Comment: @jsotola i meant when there is no current going in base

Answer (score 1):

R2 acts as the base resistor for Q1 and feeds current to the base to keep it on unless you turn on Q2 to "short" Q1's base current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN3DW0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>